# Numerical integration of a complex function with Cubature C package

Tags: c, math, numerical-methods, complex-numbers

I want to use the [Cubature](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Cubature) C package to perform a multidimensional integral of a complex function. I tried to do it in the following way for the very simple function f(x,y) = x + y*i over the square [0,1]x[0,1]. The exact result is 0.5 + 0.5i.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include "../cubature.h"

int f(unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval);

int main(void)
{
    double xmin[2] = {0,0}, xmax[2] = {1,1}, val, err;
    hcubature(1, f, NULL, 2, xmin, xmax, 0, 0, 1e-3, ERROR_PAIRED, &val, &err);
    printf("Computed integral = %f+%fi +/- %f\n", creal(val),cimag(val), err);
}

int f(unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval) 
{
    fval[0] = x[0]+x[1]*I;
    return 0;
}
```

But what I get is `Computed integral = 0.500000+0.000000i +/- 0.000000`, that is the imaginary part does not appear. If I put a pure imaginary integrand (e.g. x*i) I always get 0 as result.

What am I doing wrong? Do you know any better way to compute integrals of complex functions in C?

Comment: I don't know anything about this package, but I'm unclear how `fval[0] = x[0]+x[1]*I;` could successfully pack a complex number into a solitary `double`

Comment: is the R tag for real? There's a cubature package in R (the language).

Comment: Yes there is! You can find it [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cubature/index.html)

Comment: @AakashM you are absolutely right.

Comment: @RiccardoCavallari I _know_, but my point was: is this question related to the R package or not?

Comment: @baptiste It is not strictly related to R, so I removed the tag if this was your point, but I thought that people using Cubature in R could have gone through the same problem.

Comment: I don't have strong feelings against your R tag, but you could maybe have made more explicit how it was related to the question.

Comment: Why not simply integrate the real and imaginary parts separately? It won't have optimal performance because some of the computation will be performed twice, but it'll be no slower than half as fast as the best you could do.

Answer (score 3):

2 issues:

1) Your are declaring `double val`, but you want it to be `double val[2]`.  Your original val being a `double` in cimag(val) will always return 0.0.  Change to

```
double xmin[2] = {0,0}, xmax[2] = {1,1}, val[2] /* not val */, err;
hcubature(2 /* not 1 */, f, NULL, 2, xmin, xmax, 0, 0, 1e-3, ERROR_PAIRED, /* & */val, &err);
printf("Computed integral = %f+%fi +/- %f\n", val[0], val[1], err);
```

---

2) It does not appear you are calculating `f(x,y) = x + y*i` correctly in `f()`.  `fval[0]` is a double and can not hold the complex answer you are trying to assign.

```
int f(unsigned ndim, const double *x, void *fdata, unsigned fdim, double *fval) {
    fval[0] = x[0];
    fval[1] = x[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry I do not have "../cubature.h" to test right now.

Answer (score 0):

When you define val, do this:

```
double *val=(double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * integrand_fdim);
```

where `integrand_fdim` is equal to `unsigned fdim` - first argument of your integrand `f`.

P.S.: the answer by @chux produces Bus 10 or segfault...